# How can I use a C++ function that returns a char based on user input (cin), from a .dll in unity?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll

I've written a C++ dll and imported it to unity. The dll contains one function which returns a char that gets it's value from cin. This is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InputTest2.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    
    char DLL_EXPORT getInput()
    {
        char input;
        cin >> input;
        //cout << input; //for internal testing in main
        return input;
    }
}
```

This is the header file:

```
#pragma once

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {

    char DLL_EXPORT getInput();

}
```

When testing the function in main, it works as expected: the console prints the key I've pressed on and terminates. However, when using the function in Unity, all I get is one blank message in the console when hitting play, and then a '?' character printed every update, no matter what key I'm pressing. Function is called from update.
Here is the C# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class CPPbackend : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("InputTest2")]
    private static extern char getInput();

    void Update()
    {
        //if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        //{
            print(getInput());
        //}
        
    }
}
```

If I un-comment the if statement, I get a '?' printed whenever I press a key. I have also tried writing getInput().ToString() thinking maybe the char type is the problem, but that didn't change anything. I've also tried deleting the "using namsepace std;" line and instead writing std::cin within the function, but that didn't change anything either.
There are no errors with importing/using the dll in unity, i've also written some functions that receive parameters and return data types in a dll and imported it to unity, and it worked fine.
I've recently started learning C++, and this is just an exercise, but I'd very much like to know what am I doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Unity is not a command line app with a console and such. Where do you expect the input would come from?

Comment: `char` in C++ is ANSI but in C# is Unicode, so you would need `[DllImport("InputTest2", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]` or you can change the C++ function to use `wcin` and return `wchar_t` instead